# String index out of range error help. Pig latin project

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm doing an assignment that converts a string sentence into pig latin.

I've planned and written all the code but I get this error:

> `String index is out of range`

Below is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class project1d {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("This is a pig latin translator. Enter a sentence to convert.");
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        pigLat(console);
    }
    public static void pigLat(Scanner console){
        String sentence = console.next();
        int start = 0;
        int end = 0;
        int counter =0;
        while(sentence.length()>0){
            while(end<sentence.length()-1){
                while(sentence.charAt(counter+1)!=' '){
                    counter++;     
                    end = counter;
                }
                String word = sentence.substring(start,end);
                int index= 0;
                char letter= word.charAt(index);       
                while (letter != 'a' || letter != 'e' || letter != 'i' || 
                letter != 'o' || letter != 'u'){
                    index++;
                }
                System.out.print(word.substring(index,word.length()-1)+"-");
                System.out.print(word.substring(0,index-1)+"ay");
                counter++;
                start=end+1;
            }
            System.out.println("Do you wanna put in another? Press ENTER to quit");
            sentence = console.next();
        }
    }
}
```

I think the third `while` loop is increasing one too many times, but I can't figure out how to fix this or if that's even the problem.

The actual java errors are listed below:

> ```
> - java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4
> -   at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:47)
> -   at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:693)
> -   at project1d.pigLat(project1d.java:15)
> -   at project1d.main(project1d.java:6)
> ```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it means you are trying to get the 5th character of a String which has maximal 4 characters. test the length first.

Comment: Aside: `String sentence = console.next();` will only read a single word. Use `nextLine()` to read a whole line.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. Can you please specify what the code is supposed to achieve? Input => Output.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there are many things wrong with the code, aside of whether it does what it's intended to do or not.

- You're increasing the indexes and checking the value without confirming whether those indexes are valid.
- You are not clearing the variables before using them again after the first iteration of the whole thing.
- You're increasing the index but you got an infinite loop at the letter check because you're not changing the letter when you increase the index.
- The letter check is checking conditions that overlap - letter!= a || letter!=e will always be true, thus this makes it an infinite loop too.
- As Andy pointed out: String sentence = console.next(); will only read a single word. Use nextLine instead.

Please try:

```
public static void pigLat(Scanner console){
    String sentence = console.next();
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    int counter =0;
    while(sentence.length()>0){
        start = 0; end = 0; counter = 0;
        while(end<sentence.length()-1){
            while(sentence.length()>counter+1 && sentence.charAt(counter+1)!=' '){
                counter++;     
                end = counter;
            }
        String word = sentence.substring(start,end);
        if(word.length()>0){
            int index = 0;
            char letter = word.charAt(index);       
            while(index+1<word.lenght() && letter != 'a' && letter != 'e' && letter != 'i' && letter != 'o' && letter != 'u'){
                index++;
                letter = word.charAt(index);
            }
            System.out.print(word.substring(index,word.length()-1)+"-");
            System.out.print(word.substring(0,index-1)+"ay");
        }
        counter++;
        start=end+1;
    }
    System.out.println("Do you wanna put in another? Press ENTER to quit");
    sentence = console.nextLine();
}
```

It's just natural that your code has some mistakes, as you're still learning how to do that properly. Keep it up ;)